# Zookeeper connection refuse in cluster mode

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I want to built the zookeeper cluster in three cloud servers (centos 7) but it is desperate that it hasn't started successful yet....
Here is the conf: 
zoo1：

```
clientPort=2181
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper/data
syncLimit=5
initLimit=10
tickTime=2000

server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.2=x.x.x.x:2888:3888
server.3=x.x.x.x:2888:3888
```

The other two machines had setup the corresponding localhost to 0.0.0.0 respectively, and confirmed that the iptables and firewalld is closed.
Everytime I run 'zkServer.sh start', it prints STARTED, like this:

```
[root@VM_144_102_centos zookeeper-3.5.2-alpha]# zkServer.sh start
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/iuShu/components/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.5.2-alpha/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
```

but their state is...

```
[root@VM_144_102_centos zookeeper-3.5.2-alpha]# zkServer.sh status
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/iuShu/components/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.5.2-alpha/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Client port found: 2181. Client address: localhost.
Error contacting service. It is probably not running.
```

I can see the election port 3888 is listening by using 'netstat -tunlp' and also telnet is OK, here is the primary logs:

```
2017-12-12 22:06:58,914 [myid:3] - WARN  [WorkerSender[myid=3]:QuorumCnxManager@459] - Cannot open channel to 2 at election address /x.x.x.x:3888
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
```

I'm new to zookeeper. I had tried any ways i could find but it doesn't did the trick, maybe the reason is the cloud servers ? Hope someone can help me, please~~

Comment: Check the flags at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47580352/8978587. Avoid 0.0.0.0

Comment: Instead of 0.0.0.0 and x.x.x.x you should put the real ip address or domain names of your zookeeper nodes. Also don't forget to setup myid files in data directory.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that. Now i have successful ran three zookeeper in one machine.